# Trouble retrieving 'localised' strings from DateFormatter that indicate time using "AM/PM" format

Tags: ios, swift, localization, dateformatter

My app has a section where I indicate the current time in a graph of 24 hour strings that follow AM/PM format i.e: a set of strings from 12 AM to 11PM

I'm trying to localise the above set of strings but I'm confused.

I'm using a `DateFormatter` with a `dateFormat` of "h a". I've tried setting the `locale` property of the formatter and it does alter the string in few languages but it does not work universally.

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = .current
df.dateFormat = "h a"
myLabel.text = df.string(from: myDate)
```

I've heard that a lot of countries don't even follow the AM/PM format. So how do I go about this? Should I change the `dateFormat` according to the locale? Is it not really a good idea to use a AM/PM format?

I thought that the `DateFormatter` would handle this for me accordingly but it doesn't. Help needed! TYIA!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country#Time Remember, you are not alone, and 24h seems to be mostly used. You should always prefers the local preferences. Maybe "jj" could be the format your are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the time depending on the user's `Locale`, you can use `timeStyle` on `DateFormatter`

```swift
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("j")
// 2 PM

let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("j")
// 14
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael! The problem is that I set the locale to be `Locale.current` and the language "French" (used in this case) has a lot of versions. I just used the plain "French" language and it returns time in the format of AM/PM. The confusing part is that I'm not sure if "AM/PM" is spelled the same in every language. If yes, I could use your solution with a few tweaks. If not, I need to think about something else.

Comment: I updated my answers to take account of users preferences (the 24-hours switch in settings) and only display hours (instead of hours:minutes).  About your concern, you should let the DateFormatter do its stuff. It will display the correct format according to the user's preferences.